# I can't build linphone 3.8.5 on visual studio development environment

Tags: voip, linphone

Can anyone tell me how to build `linphone 3.8.5` on Visual studio?
I am trying to do this for one month, but failed.
I have tried in many ways by reading many answers, but failed.
May somebody help me to build it ?

Answer (score 2):

### Create a project

1. To create a project, go to "File" menu -> New -> Project...
2. Select the "Win32 Console Application" template in the section "Visual C++" -> "Win32" and give a name to your project e.g. "Liblinphone tutorial". Next click "Ok".
3. Now, the wizard for Win32 Applications comes out. Click "Next", check the "Empty project" box and click "Finish".
4. You should now have a project called "Liblinphone tutorial" and a new target identically named. You may rename this target into "Basic call".

### Configure a project to use liblinphone

1. Download the  [ZIP archive of linphone SDK](http://linphone.org/releases/windows/)  and extract it into your Visual Studio project directory. In our case, it is placed in Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Liblinphone tutorial\Liblinphone tutorial. Be care to name the extracted directory as "liblinphone".
2. In Visual Studio, right click on the "Basic call" target and click on "Properties"
3. Go to "C/C++" section and then "General". Add the directory "liblinphone/include" in the "Additonal Include Directory" field by using the editing wizard.
4. Go to "Linker" -> "General" section and add the "liblinphone/lib" directory to "Additional Library Directories".
5. Go to "Linker" -> "Input" section and add the folowing libraries into "Additional Dependencies":
      ortp.lib
       mediastreamer_base.lib
       mediastreamer_voip.lib
       linphone.lib

### Compiling

Add file called name.c in the source files of your target and fill it with the source code of the [Basic call tutorial](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__basic__call__tutorials.html)

```
/*
linphone
Copyright (C) 2010  Belledonne Communications SARL 
 (simon.morlat@linphone.org)
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
*/
#ifdef IN_LINPHONE
#include "linphonecore.h"
#else
#include "linphone/linphonecore.h"
#endif
#include <signal.h>
static bool_t running=TRUE;
static void stop(int signum){
        running=FALSE;
}
/*
 * Call state notification callback
 */
static void call_state_changed(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *msg){
        switch(cstate){
                case LinphoneCallOutgoingRinging:
                        printf("It is now ringing remotely !\n");
                break;
                case LinphoneCallOutgoingEarlyMedia:
                        printf("Receiving some early media\n");
                break;
                case LinphoneCallConnected:
                        printf("We are connected !\n");
                break;
                case LinphoneCallStreamsRunning:
                        printf("Media streams established !\n");
                break;
                case LinphoneCallEnd:
                        printf("Call is terminated.\n");
                break;
                case LinphoneCallError:
                        printf("Call failure !");
                break;
                default:
                        printf("Unhandled notification %i\n",cstate);
        }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        LinphoneCoreVTable vtable={0};
        LinphoneCore *lc;
        LinphoneCall *call=NULL;
        const char *dest=NULL;
        /* take the destination sip uri from the command line arguments */
        if (argc>1){
                dest=argv[1];
        }
        signal(SIGINT,stop);
#ifdef DEBUG
        linphone_core_enable_logs(NULL); /*enable liblinphone logs.*/
#endif
        /* 
         Fill the LinphoneCoreVTable with application callbacks.
         All are optional. Here we only use the call_state_changed callbacks
         in order to get notifications about the progress of the call.
         */
        vtable.call_state_changed=call_state_changed;
        /*
         Instanciate a LinphoneCore object given the LinphoneCoreVTable
        */
        lc=linphone_core_new(&vtable,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        if (dest){
                /*
                 Place an outgoing call
                */
                call=linphone_core_invite(lc,dest);
                if (call==NULL){
                        printf("Could not place call to %s\n",dest);
                        goto end;
                }else printf("Call to %s is in progress...",dest);
                linphone_call_ref(call);
        }
        /* main loop for receiving notifications and doing background linphonecore work: */
        while(running){
                linphone_core_iterate(lc);
                ms_usleep(50000);
        }
        if (call && linphone_call_get_state(call)!=LinphoneCallEnd){
                /* terminate the call */
                printf("Terminating the call...\n");
                linphone_core_terminate_call(lc,call);
                /*at this stage we don't need the call object */
                linphone_call_unref(call);
        }
end:
        printf("Shutting down...\n");
        linphone_core_destroy(lc);
        printf("Exited\n");
        return 0;
}
```

You can now build your project by right clicking on the target to build and clicking on "Build"

### Executing and debuging

To be able to execute the generating binary file, you need to set the PATH environment variable. Go to the property panel of the target and then in the "Debuging" section. Edit the environment field and add the following line:

```
PATH=C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Liblinphone tutorial\Liblinphone tutorial\liblinphone\bin;%PATH%
```

The "Basic call" program need a SIP address as argument. You can specify it by editing the "Command argument" field. For instance, you may write `sip:bot.linphone.org.`

You can now execute the program by clicking on the "Local Windows Debugger" in the main interface.

**Note** : Mediastreamer loads its plugins relatively to the root of the SDK. If you need features provided by such plugins, for example the support of OpenH264, you may set the working directory to the location of the SDK. That can be done by going into the "Debuging" section in the property of your project.

---

**[Refrence](https://wiki.linphone.org/wiki/index.php/Getting-started:windows)**